# What is the best way to implement an echo server with async i/o and IOCP?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, io, iocp

As we all know, an echo server is a server that reads from a socket, and writes that very data into another socket.

Since Windows I/O Completion ports give you different ways to do things, I was wondering what is the best way (the most efficient) to implement an echo server. I'm sure to find someone who tested the ways I will describe here, and can give his/her contribute.

My classes are `Stream` which abstracts a socket, named pipe, or whatever, and `IoRequest` which abstracts both an `OVERLAPPED` structure and the memory buffer to do the I/O (of course, suitable for both reading and writing). In this way when I allocate an `IoRequest` I'm simply allocating memory for memory buffer for data + `OVERLAPPED` structure in one shot, so I call `malloc()` only once.
In addition to this, I also implement fancy and useful things in the `IoRequest` object, such as an atomic reference counter, and so on.

Said that, let's explore the ways to do the best echo server:

-------------------------------------------- Method A. ------------------------------------------

1) The "reader" socket completes its reading, the IOCP callback returns, and you have an `IoRequest` just completed with the memory buffer.

2) Let's copy the buffer just received with the "reader" `IoRequest` to the "writer" `IoRequest`. (this will involve a `memcpy()` or whatever).

3) Let's fire again a new reading with `ReadFile()` in the "reader", with the same `IoRequest` used for reading.

4) Let's fire a new writing with `WriteFile()` in the "writer".

-------------------------------------------- Method B. ------------------------------------------

1) The "reader" socket completes its reading, the IOCP callback returns, and you have an `IoRequest` just completed with the memory buffer.

2) Instead of copying data, pass that `IoRequest` to the "writer" for writing, *without* copying data with `memcpy()`.

3) The "reader" now needs a new `IoRequest` to continue reading, allocate a new one or pass one already allocated before, maybe one just completed for writing before the new writing does happen.

---

So, in the first case, every `Stream` objects has its own `IoRequest`, data is copied with `memcpy()` or similar functions, and everything works fine.
In the second case the 2 `Stream` objects do pass `IoRequest` objects each other, without copying data, but its a little bit more complex, you have to manage the "swapping" of `IoRequest` objects between the 2 `Stream` objects, with the possible drawback to get synchronization problems (what about those completions do happen in different threads?)

My questions are:

Q1) Is avoiding copying data really worth it!?
Copying 2 buffers with `memcpy()` or similar, is *very* fast, also because the CPU cache is exploited for this very purpose.
Let's consider that with the first method, I have the possibility to echo from a "reader" socket to multiple "writer" sockets, but with the second one I can't do that, since I should create N new `IoRequest` objects for each N writers, since each `WriteFile()` needs its own `OVERLAPPED` structure.

Q2) I guess that when I fire a new N writings for N different sockets with `WriteFile()`, I have to provide N different `OVERLAPPED` structure *AND* N different buffers where to read the data.
Or, I can fire N `WriteFile()` calls with N different `OVERLAPPED` taking the data from the *same* buffer for the N sockets?

Comment: Is echoing data all you need? Consider using .NET. .NET memcpy's just as fast as C++. Probably, most CPU will not be spent in managed code with this workload. Many of your concerns go away with .NET.

Comment: Thank you, usr. Echoing data is not what only I need. I was just wondering in a general manner. I'm using C++, so I cannot use .NET and managed stuff. I was only wondering if I can avoid memcpy() for that purpose, since IOCPs may allow you to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is avoiding copying data really worth it!?

Depends on how much you are copying. 10 bytes, not so much.  10MB, then yes, it's worth avoiding the copying!

In this case, since you already have an object that contains the rx data and an OVERLAPPED block, it seems somewhat pointless to copy it - just reissue it to WSASend(), or whatever.

> ```
> but with the second one I can't do that
> ```

You can, but you need to abstract the 'IORequest' class from a 'Buffer' class.  The buffer holds the data, an atomic int reference-count and any other management info for all calls, the IOrequest the OVERLAPPED block and a pointer to the data and any other management information for each call.  This information could have an atomic int reference-count for the buffer object.

The IOrequest is the class that is used for each send call.  Since it contains only a pointer to the buffer, there is no need to copy the data and so it's reasonably small and O(1) to data size.

When the tx completions come in, the handler threads get the IOrequest, deref the buffer and dec the atomic int in it towards zero.  The thread that manages to hit 0 knows that the buffer object is no longer needed and can delete it, (or, more likely, in a high-performance server, repool it for later reuse).

> Or, I can fire N WriteFile() calls with N different OVERLAPPED taking
>   the data from the same buffer for the N sockets?

Yes, you can.  See above.

Re. threading - sure, if your 'management data' can be reached from multiple completion-handler threads, then yes, you may want to protect it with a critical-section, but an atomic int should do for the buffer refcount.

Comment: Having re-read my answer this morning, it doesn't seem to be all that clear.  Still, it got accepted so you must have got some help from it:)

Comment: Yes, it was very useful. The only point I was thinking about is that usually I allocate the `OVERLAPPED` structure in the *same* memory of the buffer memory, just to have only 1 call to `malloc()`. Do you think its better having ref-counter in `IORequest` class or only the buffer, and leave `IORequest` class to manage only `OVERLAPPED` structures? In the latter way I have to call `malloc()` 2 times.

Comment: 'I allocate the OVERLAPPED structure in the same memory of the buffer' yes, that is often done. I've only written 'web style' servers, not 'broadcast/chat', so this is a new area for me.  (for instance, I use WSASend() which takes an array of buffers:).  I'm kinda thinking that there ought to be a way of avoiding the extra malloc.  I'll think about it some more. It would help if I didn't have this stinkin' hangover from last nights beer festival:(

Comment: Lol! Btw, isn't this also a problem of web-like servers you worked in the past? I mean, for example, asynchronously reading files with ReadFile(), which fills some OVERLAPPED+buffer packets, and then you pass those big packets to WSASend() which will send the data to the client socket, through the HTTP protocol, for instance

Comment: For the broadcast situation I have a separate 'buffer handle' class which implements the same interface as the normal 'buffer' but whereas the normal buffer is a memory block, a WSABUF and an OVERLAPPED the 'buffer handle' is a pointer to a buffer, a WSABUF and an OVERLAPPED. To broadcast a buffer you simply attach it to buffer handles for each send. The buffer handles are ref counted like the buffers and they hold a ref to the original buffer. This avoids copying in the 1->N broadcast case and doesn't complicate the 1->1 case.